# How to count the number of documents in a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I would like to know how to count the number of documents in a collection. I tried the follow

```
var value = collection.count();
&&
var value = collection.find().count()
&&
var value = collection.find().dataSize()
```

I always get method undefined.

Can you let me know what is the method to use to find the total documents in a collection.

Comment: The second should work... When this is the mongo shell, you might have to prefix your collection with `db.` like this: `db.collection.find().count()`

Comment: It does not like count(). I get the error below - Ganesh                TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at C:\software\Enide-Studio\workspace\nodeexpress-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\collection\commands.js:55:5
    at C:\software\Enide-Studio\workspace\nodeexpress-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1183:7

Comment: I think this way is better for a specific collection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69168420/7399485

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want the number of documents in a collection, then use the `count` method, which returns a Promise. Here's an example:

```
let coll = db.collection('collection_name');
coll.count().then((count) => {
    console.log(count);
});
```

This assumes you're using Mongo 3.

Edit: In version 4.0.3, `count` is deprecated. use [countDocument](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/#db-collection-countdocuments) to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 33):

Traverse to the database where your `collection` resides using the command:

```
use databasename;
```

Then invoke the `count()` function on the `collection` in the database.

```
var value = db.collection.count();
```

and then `print(value)` or simply `value`, would give you the count of documents in the collection named `collection`.

Refer: http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/

Comment: which ever collection count you are looking for call in mongo shell directly as db.salary.count() it will return the count.

Answer (score 13):

Since *v4.0.3* you can use for better performance:

```
db.collection.countDocuments()
```

Comment: Note that this is still not a performant operation. CountDocuments does a full collection scan and is a costly query on large collections that can cause potentially huge I/O spikes.

Answer (score 5):

Execute Mongo shell commands in single line for better results.

**To get count of all documents in mongodb**

> var documentCount = 0; db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) { documentCount++; }); print("Available Documents count: "+ documentCount);

**Output:** `Available Documents count: 9`

**To get all count of document results in a collection**

> db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) { resultCount = db[collection].count(); print("Results count for " + collection + ": "+ resultCount); });

**Output:**

```
Results count for ADDRESS: 250 
Results count for APPLICATION_DEVELOPER: 950
Results count for COUNTRY: 10
Results count for DATABASE_DEVELOPER: 1
Results count for EMPLOYEE: 4500
Results count for FULL_STACK_DEVELOPER: 2000
Results count for PHONE_NUMBER: 110
Results count for STATE: 0
Results count for QA_DEVELOPER: 100
```

**To get all dataSize of documents in a collection**

> db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) { size = db[collection].dataSize(); print("dataSize for " + collection + ":"+ size); });

**Output:**

```
dataSize for ADDRESS: 250 
dataSize for APPLICATION_DEVELOPER: 950
dataSize for COUNTRY: 10
dataSize for DATABASE_DEVELOPER: 1
dataSize for EMPLOYEE: 4500
dataSize for FULL_STACK_DEVELOPER: 2000
dataSize for PHONE_NUMBER: 110
dataSize for STATE: 0
dataSize for QA_DEVELOPER: 100
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply you can use

```
      Model.count({email: 'xyz@gmail.com'}, function (err, count) {
      console.log(count);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

`db.collection('collection-name').count()`  is now deprecated. 
Instead of count(), we should now use `countDocuments()` and `estimatedDocumentCount()`. 
Here is an example:

```
`db.collection('collection-name').countDocuments().then((docs) =>{
console.log('Number of documents are', docs);
    };`
```

To know more read the documentation:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount/

Answer (score 1):

Through MongoDB Console you can see the number of documents in a collection.

1.Go to mongoDB console and issue command "use databasename".
  To start the console go up to the bin folder of where MongoDB is installed and click on mongo.exe 
  to start the mongoDB console
e.g If the database is myDB then command is "**use myDB**"

2.Execute this command db.collection.count()
  collection is like table in RDBMS.
e.g if your collection name is myCollection then the command is **db.myCollection.count()**;

this command will print the size of the collection in the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.count(function(err,countData){

//you will get the count of number of documents in mongodb collection in the variable 
countdata

});
```

In place of collection give your mongodb collection name