# How to count documents in mongodb/express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a express API and I wan't to return the documents that match the query params, as well as the number of documents.

I have the following query, and I wan't to return the following object.

```
  const property = await Property.find(query1);
  res.json({ 'results:': property.countDocuments(), property });
```

I get the following error

> property.countDocuments is not a function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count the number of documents in a mongodb collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720050/how-to-count-the-number-of-documents-in-a-mongodb-collection) making it as dup..

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```js
const property = await Property.countDocuments(query1);
```

Comment: I wan't. to return the documents and the number of documents.

Comment: Then you should simply `find` the documents and check the `length` property of the returned array i.e. instead of `property.countDocuments()` above, just do `property .length`

Answer (score 0):

`find` returns an array of documents, so you can just use, `.length` property.length

Comment: You're right but `.find()` returns entire docs in a cursor, you don't need docs to be returned, just using `.countDocuments()` will yield you a number representing no.of docs in collection. Just in case if you still wanted to use `.find()` use a projection `.find({},{_id: 1})`and do `.length`..

Comment: You right, thanks. But the question is about to return the no.of docs and docs too. Not only the count.