# Counting users using NoSQL Databases

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, backend

What's the best way to get/store the number of users that have signed up to my platform? Since I'm using MongoDB, I can't access the number of rows in the "users" database without counting one-by-one every record (which is obviously prone to be less efficient with more users).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count the number of documents in a mongodb collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720050/how-to-count-the-number-of-documents-in-a-mongodb-collection)

Comment: Yes and no. It surely works, but as @NicoVanBelle said commenting an answer on that link, this method may isn't efficient for large databases. In the last part of my question I was relating right to the link you linked

Comment: Maybe I should have just another database for statistics?

Comment: That's another approach I was thinking about. You could store a document with total user count and increment or decrement it whenever a user is added or deleted. Then when you need the count you just need to query for a single document.

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts MongoDB already does exactly that, which you can retrieve with `estimatedDocumentCount`

Comment: @Joe True, I saw that was available but assumed (maybe incorrectly) that Alessandro was only interested in an exact count. Alessandro, do you think [estimatedDocumentCount](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount/) works for you?

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts Therein lies the problem, if you keep a separate count, and increment/decrement as you add/remove users, there is always the possibility that changing the count will fail when adding/removing a user, or vice versa, i.e. the same problem that makes the mongodb count 'estimated'.

Comment: Also note that if you pass `countDocuments` a query that can be satsified by an index, mongodb can use a COUNT_SCAN over the index instead of reading all of the documents.  (check the explain plan to see)

Comment: Thanks @Joe, I've just updated this thread with the answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Joe for the answer. I'll use the `estimatedDocumentCount` method since it requires fewer resources (`O(1)`) than `countDocuments` (